# Access nested columns in transformers setInputCol() method

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, databricks

I am trying to parse a Wikipedia dump using Databricks XML parser and Spark's pipeline approach. The goal is to compute a feature vector for the text field, which is a nested column.

The schema of the XML is as follows:

```
root
|-- id: long (nullable = true)
|-- ns: long (nullable = true)
|-- revision: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- comment: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- contributor: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- ip: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- username: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- format: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
|    |-- minor: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- model: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- parentid: long (nullable = true)
|    |-- sha1: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- text: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- _VALUE: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- _bytes: long (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- _space: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)
|-- title: string (nullable = true)
```

After reading in the dump with

```
val raw = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").option("rowTag", "page").load("some.xml")
```

I am able to access the respective text using

```
raw.select("revision.text._VALUE").show(10)
```

I have then as my first stage in the Spark pipeline a `RegexTokenizer`, which needs to access `revision.text._VALUE` in order to transform the data:

```
val tokenizer = new RegexTokenizer().
    setInputCol("revision.text._VALUE").
    setOutputCol("tokens").
    setMinTokenLength(3).
    setPattern("\\s+|\\/|_|-").
    setToLowercase(true)
val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(tokenizer))
val model = pipeline.fit(raw)
```

However, this step fails with:

```
Name: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Message: Field "revision.text._VALUE" does not exist.
```

Any advise on how to have nested columns in the `setInputCol` method?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a `temp` column before using in `RegexTokenizer` as

```
val rawTemp = raw.withColumn("temp", $"revision.text._VALUE")
```

Then you can use `rawTemp` dataframe and `temp` column in `RegexTokenizer` as

```
val tokenizer = new RegexTokenizer().
    setInputCol("temp").
    setOutputCol("tokens").
    setMinTokenLength(3).
    setPattern("\\s+|\\/|_|-").
    setToLowercase(true)
val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(tokenizer))
val model = pipeline.fit(rawTemp)
```

Hope the answer is helpful

Comment: didn't it help ? :)